# How to separate my spring boot's static resource from build

Tags: maven

I am new in spring boot,
I have a multimodule spring boot maven project

```
core,
admin,
rest
```

I purchase an admin template which has more than 25000 static files(css and js).

my admin project is like

```
admin
 -src
    -main
      -resources
         -static
```

But my problem is to build admin it is taking too much time.
How can I separate these resource files from the build process?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property `spring.resources.staticLocations` in your `application.propertes` to configure a custom resource directory. IE `spring.resources.staticLocations=file:/foo/bar/static/`.

You can also configure it programmatically by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
         registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:/foo/bar/");
    }
}
```

Comment: I already used it.
   registry.addResourceHandler("/bower_components/**").addResourceLocations(" D:/UI-changes/src/main/resources/bower_components/").setCachePeriod(31556926);

Comment: how to use addResourceLocations("file:/foo/bar/") for sibling of that module?
like 
    ROOT
     |_admin
     |_UIresources
I want UIresources folder instead of /foo/bar/